# Django - get the query by date using postgresql "to_date"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, to-date

I need to get raw objects using Django .objects.raw functions like :

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_APP_DOCUMENT WHERE DATE BETWEEN to_date('0000-02-07','YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date('2027-02-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

in pgAdmin select return good result, but when i put it to django there is an error:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_task\test_app\views.py", line 110
    queryset = Document.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM TEST_APP_DOCUMENT WHERE DATE BETWEEN to_date('0000 - 02 - 07','YYYY - MM - DD') AND to_date('2027 - 02 - 15', 'YYYY - MM - DD')')
                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what is the syntax problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a string literal with single parenthesis (`'`) while having them inside the string itself. You must escape them or use `"`:

```
queryset = Document.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM TEST_APP_DOCUMENT WHERE DATE BETWEEN to_date('0000 - 02 - 07','YYYY - MM - DD') AND to_date('2027 - 02 - 15', 'YYYY - MM - DD')")
```

---

You can escape with backslash, as you'd expect. For example, `'foo\'bar'` will yield `foo'bar`.